# Updating a specific data in Mysql databasese using Flask api and SQLAlchemy from NextJs

Tags: javascript, flask, next.js

So I have created an API in flask with a PUT method in order for me to update a specific data. In my nextjs client side I have created an update handler that is responsible for handling this event in a form. But I keep getting an error.

```
"Uncaught (in promise) 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
: 
"Request failed with status code 404"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
: 
{data: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><style data-n…p":true,"scriptLoader":[]}\x3C/script></body></html>', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:125:66)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error"

Flask API:
```

```
@app.route("/api/specific_todo/<int:id>", methods=['PUT'])
def update_specific_todo_data(id):
    data = request.get_json()
    todo_to_update = Todo.query.get(id)

    new_todo_item = data.get('todo_item')

    todo_to_update.todo_item = new_todo_item
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(todo_to_update)
    # if request.method == "POST":
    #     # Get the new todo item from the request body
    #     new_todo_item = request.json.get('todo_item')

    #     # Update the todo item
    #     todo_to_update.todo_item = new_todo_item
    #     db.session.commit()

    #     # Convert the updated todo to a dictionary
    #     updated_todo = {'id': todo_to_update.id, 'todo_item': todo_to_update.todo_item, 'status': todo_to_update.status}
    #     return jsonify(updated_todo)
    # else:
    #     return jsonify({'error': 'Todo not found'}), 404
```

Nextjs

```
 // Handle update/edit handler
  function handleUpdate(e: FormEvent) {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Send the id and the new item value to the server
      axios
        .put(`/api/specific_todo/${itemToEditId}`, {
          todo_item: newTodoItem,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
        });
      // Handle success or any additional actions after the update

      setNewTodoItem("");
    } catch (error) {
      //displaying an error message to the user
      console.error("Update failed:", error);
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no experience in nextjs, what I find eyecatching is this line ```put("/api/specific_todo/${itemToEditId}"```. Are you sure that you just have to enter the url without the host? So if your flask server runs on your local machine on port 5000 I would expect something like ```.put("http://localhost:5000/api/specific_todo/${itemToEditId}"```